# 5 start rating system

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, rating-system

I'm trying to follow the example in this site: http://codepen.io/rogie/pen/jgrIu

However, instead of getting the desired result as in the example I'm getting the following: (instead of being able to click in the start, I get the start and a clickable check in top of the start)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KICJg.png)

I'm really new and I would appreciate any help.

THANKS

I created the html file with the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.star-rating{
  font-size:0;
  white-space:nowrap;
  display:inline-block;
  width:250px;
  height:50px;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  background:
      url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6eGxpbms9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGxpbmsiIHg9IjBweCIgeT0iMHB4IiB3aWR0aD0iMjBweCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyMHB4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMjAgMjAiIGVuYWJsZS1iYWNrZ3JvdW5kPSJuZXcgMCAwIDIwIDIwIiB4bWw6c3BhY2U9InByZXNlcnZlIj48cG9seWdvbiBmaWxsPSIjREREREREIiBwb2ludHM9IjEwLDAgMTMuMDksNi41ODMgMjAsNy42MzkgMTUsMTIuNzY0IDE2LjE4LDIwIDEwLDE2LjU4MyAzLjgyLDIwIDUsMTIuNzY0IDAsNy42MzkgNi45MSw2LjU4MyAiLz48L3N2Zz4=');
  background-size: contain;
  i{
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 20%;
z-index: 1;
background: 
        url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6eGxpbms9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGxpbmsiIHg9IjBweCIgeT0iMHB4IiB3aWR0aD0iMjBweCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyMHB4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMjAgMjAiIGVuYWJsZS1iYWNrZ3JvdW5kPSJuZXcgMCAwIDIwIDIwIiB4bWw6c3BhY2U9InByZXNlcnZlIj48cG9seWdvbiBmaWxsPSIjRkZERjg4IiBwb2ludHM9IjEwLDAgMTMuMDksNi41ODMgMjAsNy42MzkgMTUsMTIuNzY0IDE2LjE4LDIwIDEwLDE2LjU4MyAzLjgyLDIwIDUsMTIuNzY0IDAsNy42MzkgNi45MSw2LjU4MyAiLz48L3N2Zz4=');  
background-size: contain;
  }
  input{ 
-moz-appearance:none;
-webkit-appearance:none;
opacity: 0;
display:inline-block;
width: 20%;
height: 100%; 
margin:0;
padding:0;
z-index: 2;
position: relative;
&:hover + i,
&:checked + i{
  opacity:1;    
}
  }
  i ~ i{
    width: 40%;
  }
  i ~ i ~ i{
width: 60%;
  }
  i ~ i ~ i ~ i{
width: 80%;
  }
  i ~ i ~ i ~ i ~ i{
width: 100%;
  }
}


//just styling for the number
.choice{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  display:block;
}

//reset, center n shiz (don't mind this stuff)
*, ::after, ::before{
  height: 100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;  
  vertical-align: middle;
}
body{
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", 
  Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  &::before{
height: 100%;
content:'';
width:0;
background:red;
vertical-align: middle;
display:inline-block;
  }
}
</style>

<!-- js -->
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0    /jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/rating.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<span class="star-rating">
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="1"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="2"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="3"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="4"><i></i>
  <input type="radio" name="rating" value="5"><i></i>
</span>
<strong class="choice">Choose a rating</strong>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the JS code

```
$(':radio').change(
function(){
$('.choice').text( this.value + ' stars' );
 } 
 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample you are referencing uses [LESS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_%28stylesheet_language%29). It won't work in a web browser unless you compile it into regular css, like this:

```
.star-rating {
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6eGxpbms9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGxpbmsiIHg9IjBweCIgeT0iMHB4IiB3aWR0aD0iMjBweCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyMHB4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMjAgMjAiIGVuYWJsZS1iYWNrZ3JvdW5kPSJuZXcgMCAwIDIwIDIwIiB4bWw6c3BhY2U9InByZXNlcnZlIj48cG9seWdvbiBmaWxsPSIjREREREREIiBwb2ludHM9IjEwLDAgMTMuMDksNi41ODMgMjAsNy42MzkgMTUsMTIuNzY0IDE2LjE4LDIwIDEwLDE2LjU4MyAzLjgyLDIwIDUsMTIuNzY0IDAsNy42MzkgNi45MSw2LjU4MyAiLz48L3N2Zz4=');
  background-size: contain;
}
.star-rating i {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20%;
  z-index: 1;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgeG1sbnM6eGxpbms9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzE5OTkveGxpbmsiIHg9IjBweCIgeT0iMHB4IiB3aWR0aD0iMjBweCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyMHB4IiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMjAgMjAiIGVuYWJsZS1iYWNrZ3JvdW5kPSJuZXcgMCAwIDIwIDIwIiB4bWw6c3BhY2U9InByZXNlcnZlIj48cG9seWdvbiBmaWxsPSIjRkZERjg4IiBwb2ludHM9IjEwLDAgMTMuMDksNi41ODMgMjAsNy42MzkgMTUsMTIuNzY0IDE2LjE4LDIwIDEwLDE2LjU4MyAzLjgyLDIwIDUsMTIuNzY0IDAsNy42MzkgNi45MSw2LjU4MyAiLz48L3N2Zz4=');
  background-size: contain;
}
.star-rating input {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  opacity: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
.star-rating input:hover + i,
.star-rating input:checked + i {
  opacity: 1;
}
.star-rating i ~ i {
  width: 40%;
}
.star-rating i ~ i ~ i {
  width: 60%;
}
.star-rating i ~ i ~ i ~ i {
  width: 80%;
}
.star-rating i ~ i ~ i ~ i ~ i {
  width: 100%;
}
.choice {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
  display: block;
}
*,
::after,
::before {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
body {
  font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}
body::before {
  height: 100%;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  background: red;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! It works now. Sorry for my ignorance but don't even know what is LESS. I thought it was in CSS, actually what the example said

Comment: @S. Martin: If you look at the top of the CSS section in your codepen link, you'll see "CSS (LESS)". There is also a button that says "View Compiled." Clicking that button will give you straight CSS, which is what you'll probably want.